# Coin distribution problem to optimize

Tags: optimization, algorithms

There are $N$ users, with each user having a money request. There are $T$ coins, these coins are to be assigned to the user in such a way that its request is fulfilled. Assume each coin may have different values.
Condition : Assign each user a minimum number of coins to fulfill his request. Also increase the number of satisfied users (a coin can be assigned to only one user).

What kind of classical optimization problem is it ? It does not belong to knapsack as there is no upper bound like the weight limit as in a sack, instead here lower bound is the requested amount. How can this be approximated ?